# security concern over passing password in sql statement or callable satement

Tags: oracle, security, jdbc

I am planning to keep password hash in my database rather than plain text. What my concern is when I execute my query from JDBC in a prepared statements like:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = 'userName' 
and password = dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('password'),3);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('username',  dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('passowrd'),3);
```

or If I call PLSQL procedure which expect me to pass the plaintext password and then thse procedures will have queries like above in their body. My concern can somebody tap my passwords sent from my server to my database through these queries via JDBC. Is it better to use prepared statement or plsql procedure to overcome this security concern? Or should I hash my passwords using my java code first and then pass these password for insertion or selection?

Comment: My suggestion is not to have the password as like this. its better keep in file, which is encripted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *only* way to overcome the security issue that you quote is to pre-hash your passwords server-side prior to sending it over the wire.

That's best practice.

**HOWEVER** `dbms_crypto.hash` is **not** secure for password storage and you should not be using it. Instead, you should be using BCrypt with an appropriate salt and cost. Generate the bcrypt hash in your server code, then send it to the database already hashed (for inserts) or pull the hash from the database using the username (for selects).

Additionally, I would like to point out that it's a **severe** problem if an attacker can get close enough to your database to see the queries you're running on it. While I am a fan of defense-in-depth, so you should protect against the possibility, if that's actually happening that's a **massive** issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either encrypting the password before you send the sql with java encryption or secure your SQLNet.
For more information on securing SQLNet refer to orafaq.com they have a short and good description: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Network_Encryption

BTW: these SQL statements are not "prepared".

Answer (score 0):

ircmaxell's answer is the best solution.

If for some reason you are unable to pre-hash the value, and *must* pass the plaintext password to the database, you should at least ensure the database does not cache the statement that includes the plaintext password.  A specific statement can be purged from the shared pool, i.e. `GV$SQL`, with the following code:

```
--Remove a SQL statement from the shared pool.
begin
    for cached_sql in
    (
        select *
        from gv$sql
        where lower(sql_fulltext) like
            'insert into users values%dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw%'
    ) loop
        sys.dbms_shared_pool.purge(cached_sql.address||','
                ||cached_sql.hash_value, 'C', 1);
    end loop;
end;
/
```